# Error in gen_event.erl + proc_lib.erl when run 100 spawn (Erlang)

Tags: erlang

i have file "c:\1\0.txt" with 100 urls

and i run 100 spawn

and have error

```
(no error logger present) error: "Error in process <0.240.0> with exit value: {badarg,[{gen_event,send,2,[{file,\"gen_event.erl\"},{line,221}]},{proc_lib,exit_p,2,[{file,\"proc_lib.erl\"},{line,259}]}]}\n"
```

my code

```
-module(gsearch).
-compile(export_all).
-include("c:\\1\\ibrowse.hrl").

main() ->
    ibrowse:start(),
    {ok, Device} = file:open("c:\\1\\0.txt", read),
    read_each_line(Device).

read_each_line(Device) ->
    case io:get_line(Device, "") of
        eof ->
            file:close(Device);
        Line ->
            spawn(gsearch, url_get, [string:substr(Line, 1, length(Line) - 1)]),
            read_each_line(Device)
    end.

url_get(Url) ->
    UrlHTTP = lists:concat(["http://www.", Url]),
    case ibrowse:send_req(UrlHTTP, [], get, [], [], 10000) of
        {ok, "200", _Headers, Data} ->
            save(Data, Url);
        Rslt ->
            err
            % io:format(Rslt)
            % io:format("Request failed: ~p~n", [Rslt])
    end.

save(Data, Url) ->
    Filename = lists:concat(["c:\\d\\", Url]),
    io:format("<"), io:format(Filename), io:format(">~n"),
    {ok, IoDevice} = file:open(Filename, [write, binary]),
    file:write_file(Filename, Data, [append]),
    file:close(Filename).
```

if i  ibrowse:send_req  1 urls  - it's ok,

but if i   ibrowse:send_req   100 urls it bad

what wrong?